# Erro ao enviar formulário php

Tags: php, email

Gente estou com um formulário que outro programador fez e os emails do site não estão mais sendo enviados, eu não consigo encontrar o erro, também não sou muito bom com php. Alguém consegue identificar o erro?

Segue o arquivo `mail.php`, essas verificações ao meu ver estão corretas no arquivo de funções, mas ao clicar em enviar email está caindo no `if` `"Infelizmente seus dados nao puderam ser enviados. Tente novamente mais tarde."`

```
<?php

    require_once 'funcoes.php';

    //Determina o tipo da codificação da página
    header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

    //Extrai os dados do formulário
    extract($_GET); 

    $messageError = '';

    //Verifica se algum nome foi digitado
    if ($nome != "")
    {
        $name = utf8_decode($nome);
    }
    else
    {
        $messageError.='Insira seu Nome<br/>';
    }

    //Verifica se algum email foi digitado
    if ($email != "")
    {
        if(verificar_email($email) != 1)
        {
            $messageError.='Insira um E-mail válido<br/>';
        }
        else
        {
            $mail = utf8_decode($email);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $messageError.='Insira seu E-mail<br/>';
    }

    //Verifica se algum telefone foi digitado
    $tel = ($telefone != "") ? $telefone : $messageError.='Insira seu Telefone<br/>';


    //Verifica se algum message foi digitado
    $message = ($mensagem != "") ? utf8_decode($mensagem) : $messageError.='URL Inválida<br/>';

    if ($valueContato == 1)
    {
        if ($estado == "")
            $messageError.='Insira um Estado<br/>';

        if ($cidade == "")
            $messageError.='Insira uma Cidade<br/>';
    }
    else
    if ($valueContato == 2)
    {       
        if ($preco == "")
        {
            $messageError.='Insira um Preço<br/>';
        }
    }

    if ($valueContato == "" or $valueContato == 2)
    {
        //Verifica se algum negocio foi digitado
        $business = ($negocio != "") ? utf8_decode($negocio) : $messageError.='Selecione um Negócio<br/>';

        //Verifica se algum url foi digitado
        if ($url != "")
        {
            if (!validarUrl($url))
            {
                $messageError.='URL inválida<br/>';
            }
            else
                $site = utf8_decode($url);  
        }
        else
            $messageError.='Insira um Endereço<br/>';
    }

    if ($messageError != "")
    {
        echo "$messageError";
        $messageError = '';
    }   
    else
    {
        $paraQuem = $valueContato;

        if ($paraQuem == "")
            $assunto = utf8_decode("Formulário Quero Comprar Domínio e Companhia");
        else
        if ($paraQuem == 1)
            $assunto = utf8_decode("Formulário de Contato Domínio e Companhia");
        else
            if ($paraQuem == 2)
            $assunto = utf8_decode("Formulário Quero Vender Domínio e Companhia");

        $estado = utf8_decode($estado);
        $cidade = utf8_decode($cidade);
        $para = 'falecom@dominioecompanhia.com.br';
        $assunto = $assunto;
        $corpo = "
            <html>
            <body>
                <p>$assunto</p>
                <p>
                    Nome:   <strong>$name</strong><br />
                    E-mail: <strong>$mail</strong><br />
                    Telefone: <strong>$tel</strong><br />";
        if($valueContato == 1)
            $corpo .= "Estado: <strong>$estado</strong><br />
                       Cidade: <strong>$cidade</strong><br />";
        else
        if($valueContato == 2)
            $corpo .= "Pre&ccedil;o: <strong>$preco</strong><br />";
        if ($valueContato == "" or $valueContato == 2)
            $corpo .="URL: <strong>$site</strong><br />
                      Neg&oacute;cio: <strong>$business</strong><br />";    
        $corpo .="
                    Mensagem:<strong>$message</strong><br />
                </p>
            </body>
            </html>";

        $headers = "From: {$nome} <{$email}> \nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\n";
        $headers .= "X-Sender: {$para}\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
        $headers .= "Return-Path: {$email}\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";

        // Mensagem resposta
        $sent = mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$headers);


        if (!$sent) 
        {
            echo 'Infelizmente seus dados nao puderam ser enviados. Tente novamente mais tarde.';   
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Dados enviados com sucesso!';     
        }

    }   

?>
```

Comment: Isso acontece no localhost ou no servidor de produção?

Comment: no servidor de produção.. ta online...

Comment: Antes de exibir a mensagem de erro adicione essa linha `print_r(error_get_last());` deve dar alguns detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: vai no php.net, lá tem o uso da função mail, você n precisará escrever muito e será capaz de fazer praticamente tudo no email

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. Somente olhando o código assim talvez não seja possível descobrir qual é o erro. Você precisa fornecer mais detalhes. Talvez haja algum lugar onde você pode encontrar um log ou uma outra forma de visualizar o erro que tem ocorrido na sua aplicação.

Comment: adicionei a linha mas não aparece o erro ..... eu queria fornecer mais detalhes mas não estou conseguindo identificar o erro, não consegui debugar

Comment: Já tentou usar a biblioteca do PhpMailer com email autenticado ?

Comment: então eu tentei user a biblioteca do phpmailer, e agora esta aparecendo o seguinte erro, da falha ao enviar a mensagem e aparece SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Answer (score 1):

ou é exchange ou é imap ou pop3 a sua caixa de email. Qual é o dominio da caixa que voce esta a usar? o que tem de configurar é o SMTP para envio de email. no caso de ser Gmail, o smtp é configurado assim :

```
Descrição ﻿SMTP Gmail: um nome generico (ex. "SMTP")
Nome do servidor SMTP Gmail﻿: smtp.gmail.com
Usuario SMTP Gmail﻿: o seu endereço Gmail
Password SMTP Gmail﻿: a sua password
Porta SMTP Gmail﻿: 465
```

Comment: Para esclarecimentos use esse campo mais abaixo (comentários), o espaço maior é exclusivo para repostas, o site funciona diferente de um fórum para entender melhor o funcionamento recomendo a leitura da [tour], se tiver alguma dúvida só chamar @rray.

Comment: é webmail  o dominio

Comment: Vi que vc não entendeu os negativos que levou na outra resposta, acredito o motivo seja o fato de ter postado um 'comentário' no espaço da 'resposta', deixei um comentário para o autor da pergunta de como conseguir mais detalhas sobre o problema.

Comment: conseguir encontrar o erro usando o phpmailer... SMTP server error: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command firs